# How do I split a string (date), breaking at different characters?

Tags: javascript, date, split

I have the String:

```
September 8, 1951
```

Using JavaScript, what is the fastest way to parse this into:

I'm struggeling with the: ','   otherwise i could just split at the whitespaces.

```
var month = ..

var day = ..

var year = ..
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parse.asp

Comment: *to parse this into:* what?

Comment: @below9k For whatever it's worth, this is not a standard JS date (there is only one ECMAScript-required date format, [`YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15)), so using `Date` here relies on implementation-specific behavior that is not guaranteed to be consistent between browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if all you want to do is break at either spaces or commas, and the date will always be in that format, then you can do this:

```
"September 8, 1951".split(/,? /);
```

Which will return an array of 3 strings, of the form [month, day, year].

The `/,? /` is a regular expression that finds spaces and commas. However, for more reliable date parsing, you could go with the built-in `Date` class:

```
new Date("September 8, 1951");
```

And then use its `getMonth`, `getDate` and `getFullYear` methods to parse the info out.

*Note: @apsillers mentioned that this is not a standard date format. This is true, but almost all browsers accept it, including nodejs.*

Comment: Worked after using the Date.parse method

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick if the date is indeed a string as you say it is.

```
var arr = "September 8, 1951".replace(',','').split(' ');
var month = arr[0];
var day = arr[1];
var year = arr[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add the string to the Date Method and it will create a Date object

```
var d=new Date("September 8, 1951");// Mon Sep 08 2014 00:00:00 GMT...
var month = new Array();
month[0] = "January";
month[1] = "February";
month[2] = "March";
month[3] = "April";
month[4] = "May";
month[5] = "June";
month[6] = "July";
month[7] = "August";
month[8] = "September";
month[9] = "October";
month[10] = "November";
month[11] = "December";
var currentMonth = month[d.getMonth()] // September
var date = d.getDate() //8
var year = d.getFullYear() // 1951
```